# Arbitrary values for Bootsrap?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am currently developing a web application. I am using Bootstrap-vue in frontend. Does Bootstrap has feature in which I can create on-the-fly class? Tailwind has it [image: here]. I tried searching it in the internet but no luck.

Here is my case:

1. Color values are save in the database.
2. Every time the page loads, I will fetch those colors and create class based on their colors

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is not really an utility-based CSS framework, hence there is nothing similar to Tailwind because it's not the mindset of the tool.

Also, even if this kind of code exists in Tailwind, it can become funky pretty quick and the best thing is still to write some bare simple vanilla CSS code alongside your template to get what you want.

You won't get any performance benefit by using an arbitrary value anyway and hence it should be used for exceptional cases anyway, a CSS declaration will be far more cleaner.

Feel free to create global CSS variables in vanilla CSS for your use case.